# Kotlin refuses to infer narrowed types after explicit type checking

Tags: kotlin

What is the reason behind Kotlin not inferring the correct types in the most trivial scenarios? Example:

```kotlin
    fun test(int: Int) = if (int == 42) "42" else null

    val ret1 = test(99) // ret1 is String?

    if (ret1 is String) {
        // ret1 is inferred as String? but should be inferred as String
    }
    else {
        // ret1 is inferred as String? but should be inferred as null
    }
```

I am aware that I can replace the above logic with `?.let` and `?:` but then `continue` won't work without annoying label specification in the Elvis lambda.

I understand that my question is really broad and maybe more of a philosophical question but I really would like to understand the mindset of Kotlin and why types are not properly inferred after explicit type checks.. :x

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With the following code, there is no error in the if branch and I get the expected error in the else branch. https://pl.kotl.in/9ZnI1g6F4

Comment: How do you know "ret1 is inferred as String?"? Also "should be inferred as null" does not make sense - null is not a type.

Comment: It's what the IDEs show me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, it does. Yes if you hover on ret1 inside the first block, it still shows you `val ret1: String?`. But that's correct, the type of `ret1` is always `String?`. Doing type check on `ret1` doesn't change the type of `ret1`. When you try to access a property from `ret1`, let say `ret1.length`, the compiler is smart enough to know that it is safe in the first block, but unsafe in the second block.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, I got tricked by the IDE tooltips. Coming from Typescript where IDE tooltips adjust inside the branches to String or null, this made me panic.